# Resize event only fires once

Tags: javascript, resize, document.write

Using the javascript onresize, only works one time. I need it to work multiple times. Here is my code:

```
var hh = window.outerHeight;
var ww = window.outerWidth;

document.write("<iframe src='http://www.example.com' align='left' width='" + ww + "px' height='600px' frameborder='0'></iframe>");



window.onresize = function (){

    hh = window.outerHeight;
    ww = window.outerWidth;

    document.write("<iframe src='http://www.example.com' align='left' width='"     + ww + "px' height='600px' frameborder='0'></iframe>");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new iframe every time. It is better to just select the one that has already been made.

```
var hh = window.outerHeight;
var ww = window.outerWidth;

document.write("<iframe src='http://www.example.com' align='left' width='" + ww + "px' height='600px' frameborder='0'></iframe>");

window.onresize = function (){

    hh = window.outerHeight;
    ww = window.outerWidth;

    document.querySelector("iframe").setAttribute('width', ww+'px');

}
```

Comment: @user2268083 Glad to help. It also might be good for you to look into jQuery.